# How to add hook in seperate php page in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have submitted form values from my core php site through curl to drupal site(http://xxyz.com/drupal_hook_register.php) link. In this page i am trying to insert email,password directly into drupal database. Please  help me to resolve this

```
         // define static var
       define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd()); 
        // include bootstrap
       include_once('./includes/bootstrap.inc');
       // initialize stuff
        drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

        $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
         $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
```

Comment: which hook you want exactly to work during the content save? And what you are trying to do? Saving an user or content pages?

Comment: I wrote a seperate php page in drupal directory and trying to save the field into new record in user table (drupal database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

```
if($_POST) {
    //Bootstraping Drupal 
    require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
    drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

    $account = new stdClass();
    $account->name = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $account->mail = $_REQUEST['mail'];
    $account->init = $_REQUEST['mail'];
    $account->pass = user_password($_REQUEST['pass']); // you could use a random characters here too
    $account->status = 1;
    user_save(Null, $account);
    if ($account->uid) {
      drupal_set_message('Created new user with id %uid', array('%uid' => $account->uid));
      echo 'success';
    }
}
```

Try this as this could help you!

Comment: thanks for you answer. anway i already tried with this link http://codekarate.com/blog/create-user-account-drupal-7-programmatically